# How to get only pure records without using loop declarative way

Tags: c#, linq

I have a some people who buy bicycles.
Table looks like

> ```
> PeopleID Bicycle
>
> 1         Green
>
> 1         Yellow
>
> 2         Red
>
> 2         Red
>
> 3         Green
>
> 3         Red
>
> 3         Yellow
> ```

I want to get the users who buyed only same bike.
Output must be for this example because the PeopleID 2 has no other color bike

> 2 red

The class is

```
 class Foo
    {
        public String PeopleID { get; set; }
        public String Bicycle { get; set; }
    }
```

And function is

```
static void WhoBuyedSameBike(IEnumerable<Foo> foos) 
    {
        var tmpFoos = foos;
        var result = tmpFoos.GroupBy(x => x.PeopleID);
        var queryResult = new List<QueryResult>();
        foreach (var fooItem in result)
        {
            if (fooItem.Count() == tmpFoos.Count(w => w.PeopleID == fooItem.Key && w.Bicycle == "Red"))
            {
                queryResult.Add(new QueryResult { PeopleID = fooItem.Key });
            }

        }
        foreach (var item in queryResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"PeopleId : {item.PeopleID}");
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to get that output with  not using foreach loop with Linq for more declarative code?

Comment: You really shouldn't be iterating an arbitrary `IEnumerable` provided as input like that.  You don't know if it's expensive to iterate multiple times, produces different results when iterated multiple times, errors when iterated multiple times, etc.

Comment: I am agree with you but this was an interview question. My code-writing way stuck in my mind.

Comment: What is `QueryResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq, group by each person, get a distinct count of each bicycle color, and select the first (only) item from each group where the count is 1.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> result = 
    foos
    .GroupBy(foo => foo.PeopleID)
    .Where(group => group.Select(foo => foo.Bicycle).Distinct().Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Output it like this:

```
foreach(var foo in result) {
    Console.WriteLine($"PeopleId:{foo.PeopleID}, Bicycle:{foo.Bicycle}");
}
```

---

**Edit**

In the comments, Harald Coppoolse recommends inserting .Take(2) before taking the count in the where statement.  This would be more efficient because .Count() will have to enumerate the whole collection to get the size (unless it implements ICollection).  He also gives a second approach that is even more efficient.

However, while we're at it, I figure I minus well go farther and condense the nested Select and Distinct methods into a single aggregation, with a result that need not be re-iterated to determine if there are duplicates or not.

```
foos
    .GroupBy(foo => foo.PeopleID)
    .Where(group => group.Aggregate((a,b) => a?.Bicycle == b.Bicycle ? a : null) != null)
    .Select(group => group.First());
```

Of course, this is all just for better understanding.  Certainly wrap your head around the original version first before you learn about the Aggregate method, the terneray operator, and the null conditional operator.

By the way.  I failed to mention before that if performance is more important than readability or code elegance, then don't run away from for loops.  The code above could be made more efficient still without that restriction.

Comment: I find that coding can get difficult when dealing with nesting or recursion.  In this case, doing a select inside a where statement can throw you off.  So definitely search out these kinds of puzzles to hone in your skills for future job interviews.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That's why I'm trying to improve my code writing skills. My code also worked but i had to know the better way. I'm really happy right now thanks again.

Comment: Instead of using Count() to see if there is only one item, consider using `.Take(2).Count() == 1`,  This way you don't have to Count all 1000 bicycles that someone bought. At the 2nd bicycle you already know there is more than one. Even more efficient: `Where not ... .Skip(1).Any()`

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse, you've inspired me to append a new version.  Wondering about your thoughts on it.

Comment: The use of `Aggregate` is nice, but be aware that this only works `AsEnumerable`. `Querayble.Aggregate` is not supported by entity framework

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse @pwilcox  I combined both of yours solutions.`    IEnumerable<A> result =
                      foos
                      .GroupBy(foo => foo.ID)
                      .Where(group => !group.Select(foo => foo.Color).Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
                      .Select(group => group.First());` I am trying to understand more working mechanizim of linq.This solutions are help me a lot.